# Data type boolean or bit in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to create table in SQL Developer but I did not find the Boolean data type or bit data type.

Is their another type instead of these?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: which dbms,sql server or oracle.

Comment: You didn't provide any info needed to help you!

Comment: SQL Developer points to Oracle ... @maream, please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support a `Boolean datatype` for columns. A common work-around is `VARCHAR2(1)` or `char` with a constraint to permit only 'Y' and 'N'' as values.

if you want to create table with bool column, here the sample syntax

```
create table boolTable (
   bool char check (bool in ('N','Y')
                   ));

insert into boolTable values('Y');  -- This query insert value
`insert into boolTable values(1);`  -- This query going to fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Bit` in **SQL** can be **sequence of zeros and ones** and **not only just 0 or 1** as true or false.
It can be 0, 1, 00000, 1111, 0101010, 000111.. etc.

To create a boolean, u can use `TINYINT(1)`